# Android Studio rawQuery with LIKE

Tags: android-sqlite, sql-like

```
This is my code but no results
String sqlQuery = "WITH Ranked AS (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY " +
                        COLUMN_NAME + " ORDER BY " + COLUMN_NAME + " ASC, " + COLUMN_SYMBOL + " ASC, " +
                        COLUMN_DTLASTUPD + " DESC) AS rn FROM " + TABLE_RECORDS + ") " +
                        "SELECT * FROM Ranked WHERE rn <= 5 AND " + COLUMN_NAME + " LIKE ? COLLATE NOCASE";
                String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{"%" + "inj" + "%"};

                //String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{whereArgs[0]};
                String finalSqlQuery = String.format(sqlQuery, DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString(selectionArgs[0]));
                Log.d("Query Debug", "Final SQL Query: " + finalSqlQuery);
                cursor = db.rawQuery(sqlQuery, selectionArgs);
```

I was expecting that ? would be replaced by value of  **selectionArgs**.

Final SQL Query: WITH Ranked AS (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY name ASC, symbol ASC, dtlastupd DESC) AS rn FROM moedas) SELECT * FROM Ranked WHERE rn <= 5 AND name LIKE ? COLLATE NOCASE

was trhe response, and ? was not replaced with variable given

Answer (score 0):

It is actually via/through calls to the SQLite API that the passed parameters are bound. In your case the parameters will be bound via the SQLite API code underlying the `rawQuery` method.

So it is SQLite itself that binds the value(s) i.e. replaces the `?`(s) with the value properly enclosed i.e. `%whatever%` passed will be bound/resolved to then be `'%whatever%'` **when the SQL is actually executed**.

- more accurately when the statement is being prepared for execution
- to determine if the `LIKE` is the cause of no rows being extracted you could temporarily use `.... AND name NOT LIKE ? COLLATE NOCASE`, if there are still no results then the issue will not be due to the `LIKE` clause.

Comment: with NOT LIKE, I got same message "records not found". I've tried also something like                       String sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM (" + "SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY " + COLUMN_NAME +
                        " ORDER BY " + COLUMN_NAME + " ASC, " +  COLUMN_SYMBOL + " ASC, " + COLUMN_DTLASTUPD + " DESC) AS rn " +
                        "FROM " + TABLE_RECORDS + ") AS Ranked " +
                        "WHERE rn <= 5 AND " + COLUMN_NAME + " NOT LIKE ? COLLATE NOCASE";
                String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{"'%" + whereArgs[0] + "%'"};